# SonarQube: Add a way to break out of this methods recursion C#

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, sonarqube

We recently started to use SonarQube in our projects. So, when I build the project it gives out a critical error: "Add a way to break out of this method's recursion". here is the code

```
private Bool SetProperty<T>(T storageField, T value, [CallerMemberName] string pName= "" )
  {
    return SetProperty<T>(storageField, value, pName);
  }
```

Do you guys know how to fix this in a way that SonarQube won't complain?

Comment: Is the method ever called, though?

Comment: @CaiusJard yes it does

Comment: So how does it finish, currently? Why does it not overflow the stack?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "Add a way to break out of this method's recursion"

As already mentioned, you need to break out of that routine, it's calling itself over and over. It appears you're trying to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface, assuming because you've tagged `wpf`.

Try changing your routine as below:

```
protected bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propName = "")
{
   if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(storage, value)) return false;
      storage = value;
      OnPropertyChanged(propName);
      return true;
}
```

In the above routine, I am checking that the `value` is different than the `storage`, if it's the same, we don't need to go any further and hence we can return `false`, otherwise we can do our `PropertyChanged` and return `true`.

Answer (score 3):

Your method is calling itself, you have to break the recursive pattern.

Comment: Right.  Which means that "Add a way to break out of this method's recursion" means exactly what it says.

Comment: this is an existing code, I am just working on to get rid of the sonarqube error. Not sure how

Comment: By removing the recursion.  See how the method is calling itself?  That's an endless loop.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/30013626)

Comment: @camille You will explain to me how saying 'Your method is calling itself' does not answer THIS question ....